Retrieve source files (or package.xml) from Tooling API
I intend to identify all deprecated (deprecatedEditable) components from an Unlocked Package and purge them from the org (destructiveChanges, in MDAPI context).
So far, I came up with an algorithm that uses Package2Member to identify deprecated components from a specific package, then queries the related EntityDefinitions based on subjectKeyPrefix to get developer name and eventually generate a package.xml from those records. However, this implementation requires manual maintenance, because Entity Definition (QualifiedApiName or DurableId) does not literally match the metadata type for a package XML (ExternalString vs CustomLabel, for example). So I have to do some pretty fancy processing logic to build the retrieve file for custom labels, workflow rules, custom objects, custom fields, custom metadata definitions & records.
What would be the best way to achieve this?
